# Query to retrieve the available rooms from the inventory

Tags: sql, sql-server, inventory-management

I am developing a hotel inventory management system which supports search and booking. I am quite new to this system and I need help in writing the query to pull the available rooms from the inventory.

Let's say the user search consist of the following values :

Region Id: 1 (For example Dubai )
Checkin Date: 31-12-2018 and Checkout Date: 01-01-2019 (It should be within the valid_from and valid_to of the room_rate_types table and should not lie in the from_date and to_date of the room_rate_type_blackout_dates table and it should not lie in the from_date and to_date of the room_rate_type_booked_dates table and if it lies in the room_rate_type_booked_dates table it should subtract the booked (room_rate_type_booked_dates table) rooms from the availability column of the room_types table)

Adult 1, Child 2, Infant 0: this should within the rooms_occupancy table

My search depends on the following tables and their corresponding columns is provided within the brackets:

properties (region_Id), rooms,  rooms_occupancy (Adult, child, and Infant), room_rate_types (availability, valid_from and valid_to), room_rate_type_blackout_dates (From_date to To_Date), room_rate_type_booked_dates (booking Id, From_date and to_Date)

```
properties ( stores the general details of the property)
  pk property_id(primary key)
  region_id (id of the region)
  property_name


rooms ( stores the general details of the rooms)
  pk room_id(primary key)
  fk rooms_occupancy_id (the combination of the occupancies associated with the room)

rooms_occupancy  ( stores the general details of the combination of the 
                   occupancies in a single room)
  pk room_occupancy_id(primary key)
  fk room_id(foreign key that references the room table)
  adult,
  child,
  infant

room_rate_types (stores of the general details of the rates per room)
  pk rate_id(primary key)
  valid_from, 
  valid_to, 
  available_rooms
  fk room_id


room_rate_type_blackout_dates (stores the black out dates per rate)
  pk rate_blk_date_id (primary key)
  from_date, 
  to_date, 
 fk  rate_id (rate_id of the room_rate_types table)

room_rate_type_booked_dates (stores the booking info of the rate table)
  pk booking_id (primary key)
  from_date, 
  to_date, 
  fk rate_id (rate_id of the room_rate_types table)
  booked_rooms
```

Expected results should be something as mentioned below:

```
PropertyId, rateId, roomId, availblerooms 
1              1     1          5
```

Comment: Start by posting DDL not your incomplete pseudo-code. Your first problem is that a single property can have A SINGLE ROOM (making assumptions). It is unusual, to say the least, that a hotel has only a single rentable room. Room must have a foreign key to property - which is the opposite of what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted to create your scenario based on your description.  It works, but may lead you to more questions as to what I did and what you're trying to do:

Setup:

```
Create Table properties 
(
  property_id Int,
  region_id Int,
  property_name VarChar(25),
  room_id Int
)
Insert Into properties Values
(1,1,'property1',1)

Create Table rooms
(
  room_id Int,
  rooms_occupancy_id Int, --(the combination of the occupancies associated with the room)
)
Insert Into rooms Values
(1,1)

Create Table rooms_occupancy  --( stores the general details of the combination of the occupancies in a single room)
(
  room_occupancy_id Int,
  adult Int,
  child Int,
  infant Int
)
Insert Into rooms_occupancy Values
(1,1,2,0)

Create Table room_rate_types --(stores of the general details of the rates per room)
(
  rate_id Int,
  valid_from Date, 
  valid_to Date, 
  available_rooms Int,
  rate_blk_date_id Int, 
  booking_id Int
)
Insert Into room_rate_types Values
(1,'2018-12-31','2019-01-01',6,1,1)

Create Table room_rate_type_blackout_dates --(stores the black out dates per rate)
(
  rate_blk_date_id Int,
  from_date Date, 
  to_date Date, 
  rate_id Int
)
Insert Into room_rate_type_blackout_dates Values
(1,'2018-12-29','2018-12-30',1)

Create Table room_rate_type_booked_dates --(stores the booking info of the rate table)
(
  booking_id Int  IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  from_date Date, 
  to_date Date, 
  rate_id Int,
  booked_rooms Int
)
```

Procedure:

```
Declare @From As Date = '2018-12-31'
Declare @To As Date = '2019-01-01' 

Declare @property As Int = 1
Declare @Region As Int = 1

Declare @roomratetypeid As Int = 1

If Exists 
(
   SELECT        
      p.property_id, 
      p.room_id,
      rate_id = (Select rate_id From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid),
      Availablerooms = (Select available_rooms From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid) - 1
   FROM 
      properties p INNER JOIN
      rooms r ON p.room_id = r.room_id INNER JOIN
      rooms_occupancy ro ON r.rooms_occupancy_id = ro.room_occupancy_id
   Where   
      p.property_id = @property And
      p.region_id = @Region And
      (  --Check if requested dates are available
         @From >= (Select valid_from From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid) And
         @To  <= (Select valid_to From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid)
      ) And
      Not Exists (Select booking_id From room_rate_type_booked_dates Where @From >= from_date And @To <= to_date) And
      Not Exists (Select rate_blk_date_id From room_rate_type_blackout_dates  Where @From >= from_date And @To <= to_date) 
)  --If NOT exists, create booking and display results and adjust the available rooms
Begin
      SELECT        
      p.property_id, 
      p.room_id,
      rate_id = (Select rate_id From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid),
      Availablerooms = (Select available_rooms From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid) - 1
   FROM 
      properties p INNER JOIN
      rooms r ON p.room_id = r.room_id INNER JOIN
      rooms_occupancy ro ON r.rooms_occupancy_id = ro.room_occupancy_id
   Where   
      p.property_id = @property And
      p.region_id = @Region And
      (  --Check if requested dates are available
         @From >= (Select valid_from From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid) And
         @To  <= (Select valid_to From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid)
      )
   Update room_rate_types Set available_rooms = (Select available_rooms From room_rate_types Where rate_id = @roomratetypeid) - 1;
   Insert Into room_rate_type_booked_dates Values (@From,@To,@roomratetypeid,1)
End
Else 
   Select 'Not Available';
```

Result:

```
property_id room_id rate_id Availablerooms
1           1       1       5
```

Comment: This suffers the same problem in the above comment, that a room has many properties. How does a single room be in multiple properties?

Comment: @level3looper: I just updated the table structure with relationships. Apologies for the wrong table schema.

Comment: @Larnu.  Agreed.  I'm also not clear on having available rooms in the room rate type table that has date ranges without a master rate type table and other elements.     Not being clear on whether logic or data structure is the primary focus of concern, I threw this onto 'paper' for a starting point.

Comment: @Harry  setting aside the schema relations, does the logic represented appear to be what you're trying to achieve?  for example, is the record update and creation appropriately interpreted from your description?